# Active Directory VBS Script for Auditing a Presentation

Tags: windows, script, vbscript

Can anyone help me with this VBS script? Thanks in advance.

1. User logs in to a XP computer and a PowerPoint presentations or web page starts
2. They read through the presentation and then click a links that says: “Click here to complete presentation”.
3. When they click the link it will send their username and time/date stamp to a text file on a server.
4. The next time they log in they will not get the PowerPoint or web page presentation.

Answer (score 0):

> User logs in to a XP computer and a PowerPoint presentations or web page starts

Copy the presentation or the `.url` shortcut to `%UserProfile%\Start Menu\Programs\Startup\`.

> They read through the presentation and then click a links that says: “Click here to complete presentation”.
>
> When they click the link it will send their username and time/date stamp to a text file on a server.

In the presentation - create a macro that sends a HTTP POST request using `WinHttp` as described in [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384071%28VS.85%29.aspx) and [this page](http://www.neilstuff.com/winhttp/). (You can enable `WinHttp` for PowerPoint macros by opening *Visual Basic editor*, and enabling "Microsoft WinHTTP" under *Tools -> References*.)

In a web page - do the same using `XmlHttpRequest()` (there are way too many tutorials for it).

Some suggestions:

- Don't send timestamps. Instead use the server's time.
- Use HTTP authentication instead of sending the username as data -- this way it will be harder to fake.
- Do *not* use GET for *submitting* data, even if it seems simpler at first.
- Think about whether you really need this information, and what would happen if users closed the presentation by simply pressing <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

> The next time they log in they will not get the PowerPoint or web page presentation.

Remove the file copied in step 1.